# Cosmos DB: Query an item in an array depending on the presence of another property in nested object in Array

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I want to fetch document(s) from a collection in Cosmos DB, satisfying the below conditions

1. First, value should be equal to my searchValue
2. Second, deletedAt should not be exist in that item.

Data

```
{
    "id": "someId",
    "items": [
        {
            "value": "val1",
            "createdAt": "2023-02-20T12:53:19.148Z",
            "deletedAt": "2023-02-25T15:27:44.408Z" // add deletedAt property when new item3 is added in items array
        },
        {
            "value": "val2",
            "createdAt": "2023-02-25T15:27:44.413Z"
        }
    ],
    ... other properties
}
```

Expected Result

Case1:

Query -> I need to get document(s) with the `value`: `val1`
Expected Result -> Empty result set.

Query -> I need to get document(s) with the `value`: `val2`
Expected Result -> Non Empty result set.

I am trying to use the **IS_DEFINED** function with the ARRAY_CONTAINS function provided by the CosmosDB. But always getting invalid query error.

If I remove `IS_DEFINED("deletedAt"): false`, My query is working fine and giving me the result.
How should I use the IS_DEFINED function inside ARRAY_CONTAINS ?

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.items, {"value": 'val1', IS_DEFINED("deletedAt"): false }, true)
```

Error

```
Failed to query item for container myContainer:
 One of the input values is invalid.
```

ARRAY_CONTAINS:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/array-contains#syntax

IS_DEFINED:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/is-defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below query does the trick, however, if we use the parameter name 'value', cosmos db is getting confused with VALUE keyword we use in queries. So I have changed the parameter name from 'value' to 'val', and it worked.

```
select * from c where EXISTS(SELECT VALUE n
FROM n IN c.items
WHERE IS_DEFINED(n.deletedAt)=false and n.val="val2")
```

The above query returns the given document. And if I change the input n.val="val1". it is returning 0 documents.

Comment: Thanks Aswin, This is exactly whats i was looking for.

However, you have changed the parameter name from 'value' to 'val'. To support the value property, we can use the bracket notation.
`n['value'] = "val2"`